# Update Navigation Properties with Entity Framework (MVC3 Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my navigation property to update with the Entity Framework. I used a database first approach and set up all appropriate FK relationships. Here's what the two tables I'm working with look like:

**Rate Profile**

- RateProfileID
- ProfileName

**Rate**

- RateID
- RateProfileID (FK)
- Several Other Properties I Want to Update

One RateProfile can/will have many Rates. I built my edit page for RateProfile to display editors for the RateProfile Entity and all of it's associated Rate entities and stuck all of that in a form with a submit button. I can display everything just fine, but my changes will only persist for the model class (RateProfile) and not for its navigation property (Rates).

Below are my views/HttpPost Edit/ Models
In my HttpPost Edit method, you can see my feeble attempt to loop through and Update each record in the navigation property Rates of the model.

```
@model  PDR.Models.RateProfile

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>RateProfile</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RateProfileID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoginID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.isDefault)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.isDefault)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.isDefault)
    </div>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Dime</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Min
                </th>
                <th>
                    Max
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        @foreach (var rate in Model.Rates)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => rate.minCount)

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => rate.minCount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => rate.maxCount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => rate.maxCount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => rate.Amount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => rate.Amount)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(RateProfile rateprofile)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {
            db.Entry(rateprofile).State = EntityState.Modified;

            foreach (Rate rate in rateprofile.Rates)
            {
                db.Entry(rate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(rateprofile);
    }
```

---

```
public partial class Rate
{
    public int RateID { get; set; }
    public int RateProfileID { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int minCount { get; set; }
    public int maxCount { get; set; }
    public int PanelID { get; set; }

    public virtual Panel Panel { get; set; }
    public virtual RateProfile RateProfile { get; set; }
}

public partial class RateProfile
{
    public RateProfile()
    {
        this.Rates = new HashSet<Rate>();
    }

    public int RateProfileID { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public int LoginID { get; set; }
    public bool isDefault { get; set; }

    public virtual Login Login { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the `foreach` into `for` statement and try whether the model binding is working fine or not.

```
@for (var int i = 0; i < Model.Rates; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Rates[i].minCount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Rates[i].minCount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Rates[i].maxCount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Rates[i].maxCount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Rates[i].Amount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Rates[i].Amount)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Everything displays properly in the View already. It pulls the correct records from the table for the navigation property and displays them just fine. I'm having problem with making any changes that I make persist when I click the save button and it goes to the HttpPost Edit action.

Comment: I know the problem is not about displaying but model binding the Rates.. The thing is if you don't generate the "name" of the html elements property the binding of child properties won't happen. When you use foreach the ids generated won't be proper for model binding.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize that the foreach loop names all of the children the same thing using the HTML helper class. Thank you so much. I've been searching all over for an answer to this problem for about 3 hours and that was a very simple solution!

Comment: @JoshBlade Glad to know the solution fixed the problem and if you feel the answer was beneficial do me a favor by marking it as an answer.

Comment: I had tried to earlier, but this was my first post and I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: Ah I guess upvotes are different from the check answer. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

So what happens when you put a breakpoint on your Edit foreach statement and check what's in  rateprofile.Rates ?

Remember that a model returning from a view is not the original object you handed out, it's a disconnected one that was created from scratch in your controller function.

Also, why is Rates a Hashset? Don't mix your database referential constraints with your UI ones, as it only adds to the confusion :)

What Mark suggested here is correct. The fields on the form should be named things like Rates[0].ProfileName, Rates[1].ProfileName etc, but as you have a HashSet, I'm not sure how MVC would regenerate those into the model.

Test with the breakpoint, then follow Mark's suggestion, and I would suggest you replace HashSet with an array or list.

Comment: Mark's solution fixed it for me. The models were autogenerated from my edmx which was auto generated from my database. When I checked the navigation properties in debug mode, they were the original values, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to pass the new values to the Edit action. The whole foreach vs for(int i...) thing seems very non intuitive as a solution though.